# How to tell if stderr is directing output to a file?

Tags: c++, c, unix, pipe, stderr

Is there a way I can tell whether stderr is outputting to a file or the terminal within a C/C++ program?  I need to output different error message depending on whether the program is invoked as:

./program

or like:

./program 2>> file

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses.  I wasn't sure what to Google to find an answer for this, but Stackoverflow FTW.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try using `isatty()` on the file descriptor:

> The `isatty()` function determines if
>   the file descriptor `fd` refers to a
>   valid terminal type device.
>
> The function `fileno()` examines the
>   argument stream and returns its
>   integer descriptor.

Note that `stderr` is always on file descriptor 2, so you don't really need `fileno()` in this exact case.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you can use [`isatty(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/isatty) to tell if a file descriptor refers to the terminal or to something else (file, pipe, etc.).  File descriptor 0 is `stdin`, 1 is `stdout`, and 2 is `stderr`.

```
if(isatty(2))
    // stderr is a terminal
```

Comment: How reliable is that on windows?

Comment: It doesn't exist on Windows (unless you're compiling under Cygwin, in which case it's 100% reliable).

Comment: Was that sarcasm? Is any part of Cygwin 100% reliable?

Comment: It was more of me joshing JesperE for his choice of the word 'reliable'.  I assume he was asking whether it existed on Windows, not whether or not it worked all the time.  And it's true, no software can ever be said to be 100% reliable, but 99.999% is good enough for most people.